# MySQL cluster concurrency

Tags: mysql, ndbcluster, mysql-cluster

I have a little application that executes select queries against a MySQL cluster.

By using 1 thread to read a record the latency is x.

By using 2 threads to read records concurrently the avg latency is ~ 2x.

By using n threads to read records concurrently the avg latency is ~ nx.

Is there a way to optimize that?

I use one mysqld for 3 Data Nodes.

Answer (score -1):

- Make sure that you have uniform servers across the cluster because a slow/overloaded master node can affect performance of the Galera Replication cluster.
- Check the node status by monitoring value of these variables `wsrep_ready` and `wsrep_connected`
- Make sure that value of this variable is close to `0` `wsrep_flow_control_paused`
- A high value for this variable `wsrep_local_send_queue_avg` for a node indicates a bottleneck in network line, If this is the case, the cause can be at any layer, from physical to OS configuration and must be investigated.
- You can yourself profile SELECTs on diffrent nodes and see performance.

> mysql> SET profiling = 1;
>
> mysql> SELECT * FROM
>
> mysql> SHOW PROFILES;

I hope this information helps.

Comment: Galera Replication cluster and MySQL Cluster (ndbcluster) are two different beasts.

Comment: Oops! Most of the community uses Galera cluster , I could not make out from question? But you can ask to MySQL support regarding this issue

Comment: @Mahesh Patil, Well, your first point is something I was wondering about, so thanks anyway :)